# how can i integrate google map in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

hi i have problem in integrating google map in my iphone. when i run app on iphone simulator it run good without any error when it load on iphone screen i only able to see red dot not the whole map i have implemented this application using google map integrating tutorials from this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start
 i have provided the api key which google has assign me but when app load in iphone this nslog generate constantly

```
2012-12-31 20:36:17.132 google map[848:12e03] provideAPIKey: should be called at most once
2012-12-31 20:36:17.747 google map[848:12e03] GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 10)
2012-12-31 20:36:19.062 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:19.196 google map[848:14603] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.0.1.1154
2012-12-31 20:36:19.244 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:25.618 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:33.793 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:39.026 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:40.885 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:45.096 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:36:53.275 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:00.036 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:00.335 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:04.719 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:12.941 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:25.739 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:26.057 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:32.466 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:40.932 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:56.592 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:37:57.050 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:38:02.515 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:38:10.864 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:38:33.764 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:38:34.018 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:38:38.405 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:38:46.651 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:39:19.375 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:39:19.625 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:39:23.874 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:39:32.150 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:40:18.172 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:40:18.427 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:40:22.677 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:40:31.162 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:41:42.868 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:41:43.128 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:41:48.785 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:41:57.027 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:43:43.507 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:43:43.879 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:43:48.065 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-31 20:43:56.264 google map[848:12e03] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
```

so kindly tell me what i need to do because i waste my 6 to 7 hour on it and my boss getting angry over me please help me

Comment: Sure looks like it's not using a (correct) key, more than that is hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: GMSCamera camera = GMSCameraMake(-33.8683, 151.2086, 6);
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);
    self.view = mapView_;
    
    GMSMarkerOptions *options = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
    options.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.8683, 151.2086);
    options.title = @"Sydney";
    options.snippet = @"Australia";
    [mapView_ addMarkerWithOptions:options];

Comment: and this is the key [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBb2eaMUPD7J5Bc9eCEtJQcptCGbU4JqYg"];

Answer (score 3):

The [Getting Started page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) says:

> If you see the marker, but the map is not visible, confirm that you
>   have provided your API key.

Have you really applied for the *Google Maps SDK **for iOS***? Do you really see the *Google Maps SDK **for iOS*** on the *Services* page of the Google API Console? (In my API project, I can't see it.)

You are probably using the API key for *Google Maps API v3*, which is the wrong service for what you want to do.

It looks as if Google hasn't sent out many API keys for the iOS service yet. All you can do is to apply for the service and wait for Google's answer.

Comment: yes i am also not able to see it

Comment: Then you probably have to apply for [the correct key](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access).

Comment: i have already fill this form and register with a google mail id but not able to see goog maps sdk for ios

Comment: @adnan Did you get a mail from Google with the key? If so, it should work, if you downloaded it from the console, it's probably the wrong key for that service.

Comment: any update in regards to ios API key? nothing here.