# Google MAp Integration in iPhone I am having trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios6

I have done everything as mentioned in the `googleMap` documents for iOS, but I got this error:

> `+[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:longitude:zoom:]:` unrecognized selector sent to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make the 7 step from GMap docs?
Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab.
In the Other Linker Flags section, add -ObjC. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All.
[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763537/2842382)

Comment: thanks I forgot this …